# How to add compute shader functionality to a dx9 application targeting dx11 hardware

Tags: c++, directx, opencl, gpgpu, compute-shader

I'm using a dx9 app I cannot update to dx11.

I have some compute shaders I want to port to this app, but I don't know what can I use to write directly to dx9 textures and possibly buffers(it's realtime graphic so coping data around is not acceptable).

It have to work on Intel , Amd and Nvidia gpus (all dx11 ready) so CUDA is not an option.

I don't know if you can share resources between dx11 and dx9 devices, but it will solve all my problems.The actual scenario is to take a rendertarget from dx9 and share it.
Aquire it in dx 11 process it by the compute shader and write the content in a shared dx11 texture i can bind in dx9 for rendering.

I was also oriented torward opencl as I have read of some dx9 interop online.

I tryed to download Amd app sdk, but in documentation i didn't find any reference to dx9 interop(some words about dx10 but all documentation is focused around opengl interoperation).I haven't checked opencl sdk from other vendors.

also c++ amp seems to not work with dx9.

Do you know if this is possible and if so what gpgpu solution that can do the job if i cannot use Dx11<->Dx9 shared resource thing?

Comment: Why you don't simply use DirectX11? In dx11 you can set feature level to 9.1 - 11.2

Comment: all previous code is dx9 and cannot be changed.

Comment: However after a further research seem that dx11 to dx9 sharing is very limited to just 2d texture without mipmaps and some specific formats.So probably it's not the best option.

Comment: dx9 dost not support compute shade, i don't think you can do that.

Comment: I don't need necessarely compute shader whatever gpgpu tech that let me use shared memory and can interop with dx9 texture is ok.

Comment: Well C++ headers 1.1 of OpenCL have DX9/10/11/GL interoperability. However is quite limited, but I think it may be enough for your needs. You can convert buffers of OpenCL to Textures or objects. I think using it is as easy as enabling a define.

Comment: So even if not documented do you say that it may be included in the amd app sdk too and so easy to not require any special documentation?
I would like to try also opencl sdk from intel, maybe this thing is better documented.

Comment: I am still confused, you said all prvious code is dx9 and cannot be changed, so how can you apply the sharing?

Comment: It cannot be changed just for pratical reasons.I need a fast solution that has very little impact.So create a new dx11 device and make some kind of resource sharing is not quite the same to change radically the original codebase.I'm evaluating possibilities with priority to what can plug in as samlessly as possible.